# Tensorflow Keras dimensions not equal error for multiple labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to predict from multidimensional input to multi-dimensional output using Tensorflow 2.0.0's Keras, with the Tensorflow Datasets API.

I am using `tensorflow 2.0.0` and `tensorflow-datasets 1.3.0` on `python 3.6.9`.

Below is my example code, I also reproduced it on [a Colab notebook] (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WMccCeLOrQU4k5D2noC4S_5rMe7-krEk) which you can run:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
data = [[1,2],[11,22]]
label = [[3,4,5], [33,44,55]]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data,label))
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3))
model.compile('adam','mse',metrics=['mse'])
model.fit(dataset, validation_data=dataset)
```

In this example code I am trying to predict
`[1,2]->[3,4,5]` and `[11,22]->[33,44,55]`. However I get the error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1609   try:
-> 1610     c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1611   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 3 for 'loss/output_1_loss/SquaredDifference' (op: 'SquaredDifference') with input shapes: [2,3], [3,1].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
29 frames
/tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1611   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1612     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1613     raise ValueError(str(e))
   1614 
   1615   return c_op

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 3 for 'loss/output_1_loss/SquaredDifference' (op: 'SquaredDifference') with input shapes: [2,3], [3,1].
```

Comment: Use your dataset the following way `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.array(data),np.array(label))).batch(2)`

Comment: @thushv89 It turned out that using `.batch(n)` for positive integer `n`, for example `.batch(2) on the dataset allowed the training to work. (your answer worked)

Answer (score 0):

As per [thushv89's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276713/tensorflow-keras-dimensions-not-equal-error-for-multiple-labels#comment104761000_59276713) to the question,
using batch on the dataset fixes the code.
The original code was more complicated than this but using batch fixed it.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
data = [[1,2],[11,22]]
label = [[3,4,5], [33,44,55]]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data,label)).batch(2)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3))
model.compile('adam','mse',metrics=['mse'])
model.fit(dataset, validation_data=dataset)
```